# WLST capture the output of state('ms1') to a variable

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, wlst

I need to capture the output of the below to a variable.
I know we can get to serverRuntime  or domainRuntime() trees and get the state. But need to get the below working.

```
wls:/owb/serverConfig> state('Server1')
Current state of 'Server1' : RUNNING
```

I tried two ways:

```
wls:/owb/serverConfig> print state('Server1')
Current state of 'Server1' : RUNNING
None

wls:/owb/serverConfig> x=state('Server1')
Current state of 'Server1' : RUNNING

wls:/owb/serverConfig> print x
None
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `getState()` method of server runtime mbean.
You can obtain the server runtime mbean by navigating into wlst runtime tree or by using a lookup method.

Sample:

```
domainRuntime()
slrBean = cmo.lookupServerLifeCycleRuntime('Server1')
status = slrBean.getState()
print 'Status of Managed Server is '+status
```

See also [Getting Runtime Information](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/config_scripting/monitoring.html) in WLST official documentation.

Comment: I tried it and I get the below error:
wls:/owb/domainRuntime> slrBean = cmo.lookupServerLifecycleRuntime('owb001')
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in ?
AttributeError: lookupServerLifecycleRuntime

Comment: This is the correct answer but the there should be CAPS C for Cycle

Comment: Fixed code with CAPS C in lookupServerLifeCycleRuntime , many thanks @user3460652

Answer (score 1):

This same question was raised by Dianyuan Wang with me 2011.
Here is the steps to resolve your issue.
1. Capture the output of state command using redirect, stopRedirect command
2. Use the Python regular expression in search function to extract the desired server output.

Code snippet is here

```
            fileName='/tmp/myserver_state.txt'
            redirect(fileName)
            state(server_nm,'Server')
            stopRedirect()
            f = open(fileName)
            try:
                    for line in f.readlines():
                            if re.search('Current state',line):
                                    status[server_nm]=line
            except:
                    continue
```

Now you can apply desired logic after this block.

Cheers!!
HTH

Comment: Yes, I think this is the only way to do it, there isnt any other way without writing to a file?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am using and is working like charm

```
    cd("/ServerRuntimes/ms1")
    state=cmo.getState()
    print state
```